# Virtual lab using Vmware

Tags: dns, virtual-machine, vmware, static-ip-address

I am trying to create a virtual lab using Microsoft server 2016 as DNS server and 3 Client virtual machines (Windows 10, Windows 7 & Kali Linux).
and i gave them the below static IP v4

Windows Server 2016

[image: Windows Server 2016]

client machines Windows 7

[image: client machines Windows 7]
the same IP settings for machines Windows 10 with IP: 192.168.1.200 and for Kali 192.168.1.199

All the machines were able to ping each other but they did not have internet connection.
what is the reason and how can i fix it.
Note that the virtual machine are on VMware Workstation Pro and the lan sittings for all of them is Bridged

Comment: so your VM in the same subnet can ping each other ? what is the default route ? is IP forwarding enabled on the router ? since the subnet is a private one, NAT is likely required too.

Comment: This question is off topic here. Check the [help] section and move this to either serverfault.com or superuser.com as this forum is for programming related questions.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet yes all the machines are able to ping each other. the issue is that i can't access to the internet with these configuration. once it remove the static IP and the DNS i am able to access the internet again.

Answer (score 0):

Check adapter setting 
1.use dyanamic ip when turn on your windows machine which is your server
2.Then make dynamic IP to static 
3.then go to adapter setting enable and desible network 
its work .